# Python error in QGIS Qfield QFIeldSync plugin configure layers

Tags: qgis, plugins, qfield

I am running QGIS QFieldSync plugin on QGIS 2.14.15. It works wonderfully for packaging my data for QField but I have encountered a python error. When I attempt to package the project for QField using the QFieldSync plugin> Package Project button and click on 'Configure Project Now' if I change any of the layers to 'Offline editing' I get the following python error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\qfieldsync\dialogs\project_configuration_dialog.py", line 119, in onAccepted
                self.project.setDirty()
            TypeError: QgsProject.setDirty(bool): not enough arguments

It does not appear to match which layer I attempt to configure to 'Offline Editing'. If I leave them all in 'copy' the programme works correctly.

Have I missed something or is this a bug?

Comment: The mix of forward and back slashes in the path of the python file could be problematic.  Is that something you're able to change?

Comment: I see what you mean. It might be possible to change it in editor, but the path is automatically generated by the plugin so I think it may be a bug. Even if I can fix it someone else will probably have the same problem.

Comment: I have just tried changing the filepath to one with just back slashes but the problem remains. I am going to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved this problem thanks to the plugin creators who advised me that QGIS QfieldSync plugin is only compatible with QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas).

I have now installed Las Palmas and QGIS QfieldSync works perfectly.